# Passing URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

htaccess below diverts PDF calls to *validate.php* where name of the PDF is get with `$_GET['filename']`

Problem is, it works with URLs below but it doesn't when there are many sub directories so what I need is, instead of just getting name of the file, I should pass whole URL to validation.php something like `^(.*)$ /validate.php?request_url=$1 [L]` (*this is just an example*).

**Note:** instead of whole URL, anything after domain is acceptable.

**WORKS:**

```
http://www.whatever.com/1.pdf
http://www.whatever.com/2.pdf
http://www.whatever.com/3.pdf
```

**WON'T WORK:**

```
http://www.whatever.com/sub1/1.pdf
http://www.whatever.com/sub1/sub2/1.pdf
http://www.whatever.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/1.pdf
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

**CURRENT HTACCESS:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /validate.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

**CURRENT VALIDATION.PHP**

```
if (isset($_GET['filename']))
{
   //Do something with it
}
else
{
   //Don't do anything
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /validate.php?filename=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.pdf$ /validate.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

without the RewriteCond

Comment: +1 to you as well because yours solves the problem too however, the reason why I accepted @Jon Lin's is because his solution gives extension of file as well. Not a big deal but saves me time from writing extra lines in validation file. Thanks anyway